# Dlink DIR 600 M repeater mode slow loading for specific sites

Tags: wireless-networking, firefox, browser, internet, wireless-router

Some sites takes too much time to load like (Slant, digitalocean).

I'm using **DLINK DIR 600 M** *repeater mode* and using hotspot on asus zenfone max pro m2 android 9.

I don't know what is happened with it. Some sites take a lot of time to load.

I tried resetting modem but didn't worked.

**I can update or install fast using terminal.**

I'm using  firefox esr 68.12.

Thing was same before I install **debian 10.5** so it's nothing with browser or os.

I already have reset modem **dlink DIR 600 M** and test if things gonna change but nothing changed.

[image]

Comment: The "DIR‑600M" is a router, not a repeater?! It's not rolled out internationally only in certain countries, please provide a link! How exactly is it connected to the network? How exactly is it configured?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to give a solution at this point. But I would try to narrow down the problem first. Try to access the site directly via your main router with your the 600M connected and with the 600M disconnected. Does something change?

Comment: DIR‑600M is modem but provide repeater option to do so we can use it as a receiver.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Y5GHBz9Djw IN

Dlink 600m WiFi Router Access Repeater Mode

Comment: @Hemlata can you provide screenshots of your configuration? So it's NOT connected through Ethernet cable, right?

Comment: It is wired Ethernet connection.

Comment: @Hemlata If it's a wired connection between the routers your 600M should be configured as an access point (not as a repeater). Your screen shot doesn't show any configuration. Please make a diagram how everything (including the end device) is connected including "logical information" like IPs etc. Did you try the suggestion in my answer?

Comment: I've been using it configured as a repeater since three years from now. So I don't know what cause of such issue.

Comment: Repeater receive signal from my android hotspot and so I could access internet on pc.

Comment: @Hemlata sorry, I don't understand your setup. Sometimes you say it's wired sometimes you say it receives the signal from your android hotspot. Please make the requested diagram first.

Comment: Thanks I'll make the diagram

Comment: I've updated link with diagram. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Hemlata now it makes more sense, what happens with you load the website on the android? how much time does it take directly how much time via the 600M?

Comment: I don't have issue on android I've issue on pc that loads some specific sites so much slower approx 4-5 minutes.

Comment: Android sharing internet via hotspot to pc using DIR 600 M

Comment: what sites? how much time does android take, how much the PC? Always the same sites? For which sites does it work. You really need to answer the questions completely. Please also try to connect your PC directly to the Android via USB and check if the problem still exists then. Did you deactivate the DHCP on your 600M (please show a screenshot).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112473/discussion-between-hemlata-and-albin).